# Getting value of an array inside two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get the value of the array, but I just cant quite get to it. I'm trying with a foreach loop and with key and values. But I can't get it right. I'm working with wordpress custom field, and I'm trying to retrieve product ID, so that I can manipulate website data.

This is the array:

```
'Izbrani izdelki'
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'product' => 34,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'product' => 35,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'product' => 41,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'product' => 51,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'product' => 40,
  ),
)
'Novo v naši ponudbi'
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'product' => 35,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'product' => 35,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'product' => 32,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'product' => 51,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'product' => 37,
  ),
)
'Najbolj prodajani izdelki'
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'product' => 34,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'product' => 41,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'product' => 35,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'product' => 51,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'product' => 39,
  ),
)
'Odprodaja'
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'product' => 36,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'product' => 34,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'product' => 41,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'product' => 51,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'product' => 41,
  ),
)
```

And I'm trying to retrieve value "product", to be more specific the value number that's inside with this approach:

```
    <?php foreach ($tabTitle as $key => $value): ?>
       
        <?php foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2): ?>
            <?php 
                echo "<pre>";
                var_dump( $value2); 
                echo "</pre>";
                ?>
        
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Always var_export your input array and paste it in your question. Avoid putting screenshots of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did like this and it works now..

```
  <?php foreach ($tabTitle as $key => $value): ?>
       
        <?php foreach ($value['products'] as $key2 => $value2): ?>
            <?php 
                echo "<pre>";
                var_export( $value2['product']); 
                echo "</pre>";
                
                ?>
        
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: If you just want to print the nested array values, then this is ok. I have removed my answer.